# How to ignore the invalid SSL certificate error in Firefox on iOS?

Tags: firefox, ios

I've just switched to Firefox from Safari in iOS just after its release.

**How can I ignore the invalid SSL Certificates error and bypass it in the newly released iOS version of Firefox?**

I can't find any button to bypass it and big blue `Try again` just refreshs.

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a really, really, really bad idea. Why do you want to allow invalid certificates? There _are_ some good reasons for it, but it's worth checking.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton This is my university website and I have to use it by the way. I'm bypassing this error for years. Now I need a "I take the risk and continue" button.

Comment: Your university _sucks_. No, really, they need to fix that.

Comment: At least they should give you a certificate to install to the device. So yeah, your university's IT department is lacking.